# Check if a relation already exist between two entities/models having 2 lists/querysets of them

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models: A, B and C.

- A has a type that defines if B or C can connect to it
- B has a OnetoOneRelation to A
- C has a OnetoOne relation to A

---

```
class A(models.Model):
    type = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=A_TYPE_CHOICES, default=ACCOUNT_TYPE_B
        )

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='b', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='c', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I need:

- get all accounts that are type B but a B Objects is not related
- same as 1 for C

So, I have:

```
a_type_b = Account.objects.filter(type=ACCOUNT_TYPE_B)
```

There are any was to check if B model/object is already attached/related instead of looping thru all accounts and check ?, because this can take a lot of time and queries and is not efficient

3. Do no let C connect to a type_B account and vice-versa on model create/update.

Comment: Can you share your models and relevant code instead of describe it?

Comment: Please show real code. `a = A.objects.filter()` is not a field definition and doesn't make sense at class level.

Comment: @DanielRoseman really sorry, it was an editing issue, I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter by [__isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) for `pk` of the related model, for example:

```
A.objects.filter(type=A.ACCOUNT_TYPE_B, b__pk__isnull=True)
```